# Is it possible to change the default exchange in easynetq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm having trouble at the moment with running multiple environments simultaneously with [`easynetq`](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/wiki/The-Advanced-API)

When I publish a message on my `dev` environment the message is also picked up in my `staging` and `acceptance` environments.

The way around this is to create an exchange per environment using the advanced bus with something like

```
string exchangeName = String.Format("MyProject_{0}", environmentName);
return advancedBus.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Direct);
```

However I now can't figure out how to make this the default exchange that will be used if I resolve an `IBus` interface.

Can this be done or do I have to go down the route of only using the `IAdvancedBus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't share the same RabbitMQ virtual host between different environments. It's like expecting a single SQL database to handle dev, test and live.

Have different configurations for each environment maintained in environment specific App(Web).config files (or use some kind of tokenisation). Each config should maintain a unique EasyNetQ connection string. You can have them all use the same broker, but have them connect to different virtual hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't know about vhosts but that is a  nicer solution than adding in a prefix to all queues/exchanges.